# NotImplementedError, RuntimeError: Too many failed attempts to build model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

I'm trying to build a model around my own dataset, but the model won't compile.
It keeps giving me the following errors: NotImplementedError, RuntimeError: Too many failed attempts to build model.

This is my code:

```
import tensorflow
import pandas as pd

# import HPT requirements
from kerastuner import HyperModel
#import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (
    Dense,
    Dropout,
    #Flatten,
)

# load data
ds = pd.read_csv("datasets/ds1.csv")

# preprocessing data
jaartallen = ds.pop("jaartallen")
y = ds.pop("inkomstenbelasting")
y_train = y.drop(index=[6, 15, 19, 23], axis=0)
y_test = y.loc[[6, 15, 19, 23]]

x_train = ds.drop(index=[6, 15, 19, 23], axis=0)
x_test = ds.loc[[6, 15, 19, 23]]

print(x_train.shape)

# ANN model
class ANNHyperModel(HyperModel):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, num_classes, layers):
        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.layers = layers

    def buildModel(self, hp):
        model = keras.Sequential()

        # add first layer
        model.add(Dense(
                    units=6, 
                    input_shape=self.input_shape,
                    activation='relu'))

        # add middle layers
        for i in range(layers):
            model.add(
                Dense(
                    units=hp.Int(
                        'units',
                        min_value=1,
                        max_value=10,
                        step=5,
                        default=30
                    ),
                    activation=hp.Choice(
                        'dense_activation',
                        values=['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid'],
                        default='relu'
                    )
                )
            )

            model.add(
                Dropout(
                rate=hp.Float(
                    'dropout',
                    min_value=0.0,
                    max_value=0.5,
                    default=0.25,
                    step=0.05
                    )
                )
            )

        # add output layer
        model.add(
            Dense(self.num_classes, activation='softmax'))

        # compile model
        model.compile(
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
                hp.float(
                    'learning_rate',
                    min_value=2E-2,
                    max_value=4E-2,
                    sampling='LOG',
                    default=3E-2),
            loss=['sparse_categorical_crossentropy'],
            metrcis=['accuracy']))

        return model

NUM_CLASSES = 65000
INPUT_SHAPE = x_train.shape
LAYERS = 5

hypermodel = ANNHyperModel(num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE, layers=LAYERS)

from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch

MAX_TRIALS = 20
EXECUTION_PER_TRIAL = 2

tuner = RandomSearch(
    hypermodel,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    seed=1,
    max_trials=MAX_TRIALS,
    executions_per_trial=EXECUTION_PER_TRIAL,
    directory='random_search',
    project_name='inkomstenbelasting'
)
```

So I tried changing the input shape, but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with my dataset.
I'm new to hyperparameter tuning so maybe I made a small stupid mistake in writing the model, but I can't find it.

Edit:
This is the entire first error:

Invalid model 0/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
Invalid model 1/5  File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 57, in build
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Traceback (most recent call last):
Invalid model 2/5
File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 57, in build
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 57, in build
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
Invalid model 3/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 57, in build
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
Invalid model 4/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 104, in build
model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 57, in build
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
Invalid model 5/5Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 104, in build

```
model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
```

File "C:\Users\Izzy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\kerastuner\engine\hypermodel.py", line 57, in build
raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Comment: you did not include what is NotImplemented, you must have forgot to implement something and it must be shown in that error.

Comment: @faheem I just edited my post to include the entire first error. It doesn't seem to say what is missing

Answer (score 1):

In my case at least the problem was created in line 127 redirecting to the function `build` at line 77 of the class `HyperModel` raising the NotImplementedError in hypermodel.py.
To solve this I simply had to rename my model building function in my `ANNhypermodel` class to `build`.
That solved the issue for me.